# Multi-line email mask with jquery.inputmask

Tags: jquery, jquery-inputmask

I'm using [jquery.inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask) for a form in my application.  I'd like one of the fields to allow the user to enter multiple email addresses, one per line.  On each line, I'd like the inputmask for email to appear.

I attempted to do it like this:

```
Inputmask.extendAliases({
    "multi-email": {
        alias: "email",
        groupmarker: {start: "(", end: ")"},
        mask: "(*{1,64}[.*{1,64}][.*{1,64}][.*{1,63}]@-{1,63}.-{1,63}[.-{1,63}][.-{1,63}][\n]){+}"
    }
});
```

The value I used for mask is basically:

```
"(the_original_email_alias_mask_value)[\n]){+}"
```

Basically, taking the original email alias mask, appending an optional newline, then making the whole mess optionally repeatable.

It doesn't work.  In firefox, I get a mask for the first email address, but after the newline I can type anything and there's no mask.

On IE, I can enter a newline but nothing else.

Is what I'm after possible with this plugin?  If not, is there an alternative?